# Sql Server On Update Cascade With Multiple Constraints On Multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers, foreign-keys

I've seen questions similar to mine, but none exactly the same.

Suppose, I have the following (simplified) tables:

**Table A**

```
aID int PRIMARY KEY
10
11
```

**Table B**

```
bID int PRIMARY KEY, aID int FOREIGN KEY referencing A.aID
100, 10
101, 11
```

**Table C**

```
cID int PRIMARY KEY, bID int FOREIGN KEY referencing B.bID
1001, 101
```

**Table D**

```
aID int, bID int, cID int
11, 101, 1001
```

I want Table D to be constrained so that:

1. `aID`, `bID`, `cID` are all valid ID values
2. `aID` and `bID` are a valid pair from Table B
3. `bID` and `cID` are a valid pair from Table C

Number 1. is easy to take care of with Foreign key constraints.

But suppose I update table C to instead be

```
1001, 100
```

How can I make sure table D is automatically updated to be

```
10, 100, 1001
```

Notice that 2 fields have to change here in order to satisfy 2. and 3. above. Is there a way to do this with Foreign keys, or is an AFTER UPDATE trigger the only way?

Answer (score 0):

According to my point in this type of case don't create other table D with select all the data based on inner join of table (A-B)-C in your case y create table D by sql select statement but define one extra trigger for update on B,C so they can truncate the table D so D is reconstruct again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing Table D to be a `VIEW` that is a `JOIN` of Tables B and C.

```
CREATE VIEW D AS
SELECT BB.aID, BB.bID, CC.cID FROM B BB
JOIN C CC
ON CC.bID = BB.bID
```

Once I realized doing this gave me what I wanted, it became much, much simpler to manage.